# access cells in matlab in different iterations

Tags: matlab

I have this code:

```
M2=[];
for t=1:numel(neighh1{1})
  for k = 1:numel(neighh1{3})
      x = neighh1{1}(t);
      y = neighh1{3}(k);
    if N(x,y)
      M2(end+1,:) = [x y];
    end
  end
end
```

where `neighh1` is a 1 by 10 cell:

```
neighh1 =

Columns 1 through 6

[5x1 double]    [3x1 double]    [3x1 double]    [7x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [5x1 double]
Columns 7 through 10

[4x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [3x1 double]    [4x1 double]
```

N is 2-dimensional array of 0 & 1

I want to do the same thing but not just for `neighh1{1}` and `neighh1{3}`, I want to access different cells in neighh1 in each iteration. For example: I want to access `neighh1{1}` and `neighh1{3}` in the first iteration, then I want to access `neighh1{3}` and `neighh1{8}` in the second iteration . Given that the number of iteration is variable based on my design. Then for each iteration I want to save the result. How could I do such thing?

I tried to modify the above code by this code:

```
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        if i~=j
           for t=1:numel(neighh1{i})
              for k = 1:numel(neighh1{j})
                 x(i) = neighh1{i}(t);
                 y(j) = neighh1{j}(k);

                 if N(x(i),y(j)) 
                     M(i,j) = mat2cell([x(i), y(j)],length(N(x(i),y(j))),2);
                 end
              end
           end
        end
     end 
 end
```

However, I get this error:

```
The following error occurred converting from cell to double:
Error using double
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert `[x(i), y(j)]` into a 1D cell array?  In that case, all you have to do is `M(i,j) = {x(i), y(j)};`.  There is no need to call `mat2cell`.

Comment: In your inner-loop, you are aware that the contents of `M(i,j)` get overwritten for each `(t,k)`, right? Based on this remark, the two innermost loops could be deleted in order to keep only the last combination. I'm assuming that's not what you're trying to do though.

Comment: @rayryeng I tried this code , but I keep getting the same error!

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I want to save the value of M in each iteration

Comment: @user3685062 - Is it possible that `x(i)` and `y(j)` are empty? This is the only other time that this code will fail.

Comment: @user3685062 Which iteration are you talking about?

Comment: @rayryeng No they could not be empty but they could be a 2_D array with rownb by 2 dimention

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Imeant by the outer loops with i and j indecies as M may have different values when i or j changes

Comment: Why are you doing `x(i)` and `y(j)`? Do you need to save these values at every iteration? Can't you just assign them to a single variable for each one?  Also, try pre-allocating `x`, `y` and `M` before running this code: `x = zeros(n,1); y = zeros(n,1); M = cell(n,n);`.

Comment: BTW, you are assigning a **vector of two points** to a **single** location in a matrix.  You can do this for a cell array, but you **can't** do this for a numeric matrix.  I thought `M` was a cell array, which is why I overlooked it.  What is the type of `M`?  If it's a cell array, you need to make sure that `M` is a cell array by doing `M = cell(n,n);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, for any given columns `n1` and `n2`, you are trying to build the matrix M of pairs `(x1,x2)` where `x1 in n1` and `x2 in n2`. Your cell `neigh` contains `N` columns of different sizes.

Based on this assumption, here is what I think you are trying to do:

```
% Your cell with columns of different length
neigh = {}; 
N = length(neigh);

% We already know how many pairs of columns there are
npairs = N * (N-1) / 2;
M      = cell(1,npairs);
pcount = 1;

% Iterate on each pair of columns
for n1 = 1:N
for n2 = n1+1:N 

    % Compute the matrix of pairs (x1,x2) given columns n1 and n2
    [x1,x2]   = meshgrid( neigh{n1}, neigh{n2} );
    M{pcount} = [ x1(:), x2(:) ];
    pcount    = pcount + 1;

end
end
```

There two significant optimizations here, so bear with me:

- You have to realize that taking columns `c1` and `c2` is a symmetric process, therefore your indices `i` and `j` should not run on "the matrix without diagonal" (ie, both distinct and running between 1 and `N`), but only on the "lower-triangular part" (see the loops with `n1` and `n2` below).
- Then, for given columns `n1` and `n2`, computing the matrix of pairs of elements in these columns is best achieved using the function `meshgrid` (read the documentation).

There is one part that I left out in your example because I don't have enough information about it. The matrix `N` does not appear in the previous code. However, it is my understanding that N is only given as a "filter" on which pair should be taken; you can apply this filter after the assignment `M{pcount} = [ x1(:), x2(:) ];` if you want.